# Can we use both Xcode 10.2.1 and Xcode 11 beta in new macOS Catalina 10.15 beta

Tags: xcode, macos, beta

Currently I'm using macOS 10.14.5 and Xcode 10.2.1, the stable versions which Apple released. I'm wondering to install new macOS Catalina 10.15 beta and Xcode 11 beta for my Mac. But I want to keep both Xcode versions (Xcode 10.2.1 and Xcode 11 beta) because I'm doing updates for my apps every week which is currently in the App Store.

- If I upgrade the macOS to beta, would that be a problem for me to do
  updates for my apps in App Store?
- And is it possible to keep both Xcode versions in Catalina?
- And if I accidentally opened the project in Xcode beta, then would
  that be a problem when I open it in Xcode 10.2.1?

Comment: Yes you can run all three, doing it now, but I'm fortunate enough to have a spare Mac to do so with.  You can run multiple versions of Xcode, but I tend to only run the latest release and beta to keep track of everything that will break in feature releases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.**
You shouldn't install the beta version of Catalina as the main OS on your work machine. One of many reasons for this is that you'll not be able to submit updates for your existing apps from a beta OS.

You can however easily install Catalina on a different APFS Volume. Create the new volume in Disk Utility, and then go through the install process for Catalina. It will ask you which volume you want to install on.

**2.**
You can easily have two versions of Xcode installed. Just make sure they're named differently.

**3.**
If you do accidentally open a project with Xcode 11, then just don't commit the changes that Xcode 11 will have made, and reset relevant files in source control.

Comment: so assume that I installed catalina to another APFS Volume. then does is ask to select a OS to open  when start up

Comment: Yes, you can hold down the Option key at startup to choose: https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT202796

Comment: How do you install multiple versions of Xcode when the App Store only shows the latest version?

Comment: @LukePighetti Just download them from here: https://developer.apple.com/download/ (for the main/current versions & betas) or here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ (for other versions)